# Compute the infimum of an integral function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Let 
\begin{equation}
S(x)= \int_{x_0}^x exp (- \int_{x_0}^y2\frac{[\beta(N-z)-\alpha]}{[\beta(N-z)+\alpha]}dz)dy
\end{equation}
with $x_0\in (0,N+\frac{\alpha}{\beta})$ and I need to compute $\inf_{x \in [0,N+\frac{\alpha}{\beta}]}S(x)$.
I compute the integral in $dz$ obtaining
\begin{equation}
2\{y-x_0+\frac{2\alpha}{\beta}(log(\frac{\beta(N-y)+\alpha}{\beta(N-x_0)+\alpha})) \}
\end{equation}
But now, I don't know how conclude...any suggestion?

Comment: @Qmechanic Sorry...I made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

$\inf_{x \in [0,N+\frac{\alpha}{\beta}]}S(x)=S(0)$, and it is a minimum. This because $S'(x)$ is strictly positive and so $S(x)$ strictly increasing.